# How to append an object to several elements?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a form including several select elements with the same choices. I first create the options with

```
var myArray = [];
$.each(someJSONObj , function(key , value){
    var op = $("<option></option>").attr("value", value.id).text(value.name);
    myArray.push(op);   
});
```

and them add it to the select elements with

```
$.each($("select[id^='clan']"), function(){
    $(this).empty().html(myArray);
});
```

but the options are only visible on the last select.

I'm quite new to jQuery and I'm not sure what

```
$("<option></option>").attr("value", value.id).text(value.name)
```

returns (`alert($.type(op))` display "object", which does not help much).

What object is it? How can I append it several times to different elements?

Or maybe easier and faster: how can I convert the `op` variable into a string, i.e. how do I get

```
"<option value=myid>myname</option>"
```

from

```
$("<option></option>").attr("value", myid).text(myname)
```

and then append it to my select elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use simple string concatenation for setting options like:

```
$.each(someJSONObj , function(key , value){
    var op = "<option value='"+value.id+"'>"+value.name+"</option>"
    myArray.push(op);      
});

$.each($("select[id^='clan']"), function(){
    $(this).empty().html(myArray.get().join(''));
});
```

[**`FIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/an0uxoz0/)

Comment: Yes, good old javascript for `op`, I'll do that, thanks. Any pointer to how to get the html string from the jQuery object `$("<option></option>").attr("value", value.id).text(value.name);`?

Comment: @jul you can use `.wrap('<div>').parent().html()` to convert the op object to string;

Comment: or just `op.wrap('<div/>').prop('outerHTML')`

Comment: FYI just `op.prop('outerHTML')` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need one minor change in your code. `myArray` should not be array but empty jQuery object.

so do this -

```
var myArray = $();
```

Rest of the codes will remain the same and all functionality will be as expected.

Alternatively, you can push elements like this

```
$.each($("select[id^='clan']"), function(){
    $(this).empty().html(myArray.join(''));
});
```

Comment: None of these options seem to work (no errors but options are not set).

Answer (score 0):

I used `.wrap('<div>').parent().html()` in end of your op variable. so it returns text instead of an object.here is [PLUNCKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/tk7eNUDse2kvWTjuJ0co)

first I wrap the object with `<div>` and then get HTML of that `div`,which is a simble text not an object.
but best way is to use simple string concating I think;

```
$.each(someJSONObj , function(key , value){
   var op = $("<option></option>").attr("value", value.id).text(value.name).wrap('<div>').parent().html();
    myArray.push(op);   
});
```